# Openapi spec design for network equipment

Tags: rest, networking, openapi

I'm working on some API service which consume REST queries (CRUD operations) and send appropriate CLI commands to some network equipment.
There is 2 possible ways to design Openapi specification for this service:

1. Detailed huge API spec. Describe exactly all the endpoints, all the schemas, all the params that exist in the network equipment CLI. I think specification will be about 100K of lines in this way. Specification can be autogenerated based on device CLI parsing (using ? and TAB keys).
2. Generalized tiny API spec. Hide all device configuration details in a few common parameters. Something like

```
    paths:
      /api/{CLI_endpoint}: # we say "CLI_endpoint" instead of describing all the endpoints
       ...
        post:
          requestBody:
            content:
              application/json:
                schema:
                  type: object # we say "object" instead of describing all the params
```

In this way we simply say that all the endpoint names and param names correspond to network equipment CLI documentation.

Which of the ways will be better?

Comment: You shouldn't invent the wheel.. :) https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8040 (RESTCONF) answers your need

Comment: @NoamRathaus, I know about restconf. Maybe I forgot to say that I'm talking about specific equipment of specific vendor, not about network equipment in general.
This specific equipment does not support restconf out of the box and does not fully  comply with existing yang models. So I need my own model (and I prefer openapi compared to yang).

Comment: You are going to work hard to invent the wheel, good luck - restconf is not the only solution - building from scratch would get you into a lot of issues, like CLI problems (network equipment needs time to respond, for example) complexity of large configuration files, which NETCONF (and RESTCONF) resolve and handle